# how to provide horizontal gap between view

Tags: android, imageview

In my application,I have the `ImageView`,but Images are too close to each other,I want to give spaces between two Images. How to do it programmatically,please help me to resolve it.

**MainActivity**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 

            position= getPosition(position); 
            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]); 

            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200 ,200)); 

            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); 
            return i; 
        }
```

**main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

<view
  class="il.yapps.views.ciclegallery.YappsCircleGallery"  android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_height="250px" android:layout_margin="5dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did u try for margins for imageviews?

Comment: @  Amrut yes i tried that

Comment: Didn't giving margin resolved your problem? Can you please post related code ?

Comment: create custom layout inflate inside getView.

Comment: @  User22791 related code ???

Comment: you said u tried with giving margins.

Comment: @  User22791 i post my xml,you can see that

Comment: yes, I saw that but for your info, `android:layout_margin` will override the values you specified with `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight`

Comment: @ User22791 after removing android:layout_margin also i'am not getting space between imageview

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom `view` like..

```
     <View
       android:id="@+id/View2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="1.5dp"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewofmembers"
       android:layout_margin="5sp"/>
```

Comment: @ Aksh i need horizontal space,not vertical

Comment: you just have `inflate` this `view` after your `ImageView` it will create space between two `ImageView`..with height `1.5dp`

Comment: @Himani android:spacing (in XML) or setSpacing(int) (in Java)

Comment: @ Aksh there is nothing like abovevthings in xml or in java,i mean not showing anything